# how do i select a line of code that will loop in vue js?

Tags: forms, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2, v-for

I want the legend tag not to follow the loop. is it true, if I write a legend tag in the same block as the form tag?

```
        var app = new Vue({
        el : '#container',
        data : {
            menus : [
                {formm : "Name"},
                {formm : "Age"},
                {formm : "Address"},
            ]
            }
        }
    )
    <div id="container">
        <form v-for="menu in menus">
            <legend> Form </legend>
            <label >{{menu.formm}}</label>
            <input type="text" name="menu.formm" />
        </form>
    </div> ``
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope iv'e got your question right,

You are currently creating a form element for every menu in the menus array.
Everything in this form element will be a part of each loop... If you want the legend not to be a part of it - you need to take it out of the lopped element, meaning above/ below the lopped on form.

something like this:

```
 <div id="container">
    <legend> Form </legend>
    <form v-for="menu in menus">
        <label >{{menu.formm}}</label>
        <input type="text" name="menu.formm" />
    </form>
</div>
```